# I am trying to make 4 stylised cards in html with different positions that display info but they are not formatting correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this in HTML/CSS

[Image design in Figma of what I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OZLE.png)

And currently It looks like this
[Current way it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ToT5.png)

I am not sure why it is formatting like that and to clarify I haven't made the other 2 cards yet because I was trying to get the first 2 right.

Here is the HTMl code for it (don't mind the class names please)

```
         <div class="v10_8">
            <div class="v10_9"></div>
            <div class="v10_15">
               <div class="v10_14"><span class="v10_10">CAREY</span><span class="v10_11">1</span></div>
               <span class="v10_12">On 56 Points</span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="v10_16">
            <div class="v10_17"></div>
            <div class="v10_18">
               <div class="v10_19"><span class="v10_20">STANWAY</span><span class="v10_21">2</span></div>
               <div class="v10_40"><span class="v10_22">On 40 Points</span><span class="v10_39">16 points behind Carey</span></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

And here is the CSS code for it:

```
  width: 262px;
  height: 617px;
  background: url("../images/v10_23.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 65px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v10_8 {
  width: 262px;
  height: 276px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 44px;
  border-top-right-radius: 44px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 44px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 44px;
  box-shadow: -10.746728897094727px 9.851167678833008px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09000000357627869);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v10_9 {
  width: 267px;
  height: 96px;
  background: rgba(248,228,125,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v10_15 {
  width: 135px;
  height: 210px;
  background: url("../images/v10_15.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 44px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 29px;
  left: 65px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v10_14 {
  width: 94px;
  height: 138px;
  background: url("../images/v10_14.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 17px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 21px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v10_10 {
  width: 94px;
  color: rgba(21,21,21,1);
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-family: Folito;
  font-weight: Medium;
  font-size: 29px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v10_11 {
  width: 30px;
  color: rgba(21,21,21,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 52px;
  left: 32px;
  font-family: Folito;
  font-weight: Bold;
  font-size: 71px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v10_12 {
  width: 135px;
  color: rgba(21,21,21,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 183px;
  left: 0px;
  font-family: Folito;
  font-weight: Medium;
  font-size: 22px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v10_16 {
  width: 262px;
  height: 276px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 341px;
  left: 1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 44px;
  border-top-right-radius: 44px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 44px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 44px;
  box-shadow: -10.746728897094727px 9.849809646606445px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09000000357627869);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v10_17 {
  width: 267px;
  height: 96px;
  background: rgba(119,221,119,1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v10_18 {
  width: 167px;
  height: 241px;
  background: url("../images/v10_18.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 44px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v10_19 {
  width: 135px;
  height: 138px;
  background: url("../images/v10_19.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 17px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v10_20 {
  width: 135px;
  color: rgba(21,21,21,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-family: Folito;
  font-weight: Medium;
  font-size: 29px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v10_21 {
  width: 42px;
  color: rgba(21,21,21,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 52px;
  left: 46px;
  font-family: Folito;
  font-weight: Bold;
  font-size: 71px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v10_40 {
  width: 167px;
  height: 57px;
  background: url("../images/v10_40.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 183px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.v10_22 {
  width: 137px;
  color: rgba(21,21,21,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 15px;
  font-family: Folito;
  font-weight: Medium;
  font-size: 22px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
.v10_39 {
  width: 167px;
  color: rgba(21,21,21,1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 0px;
  font-family: Folito;
  font-weight: Medium;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: left;
}
```

I understand the design may look slightly hard to code but I will try.
I would appreciate it if someone can help me thanks.

Comment: I think your css is incomplete

Comment: why are you using top and left attributes? Try to play with them and you will get what you want. Also your css is incomplete and duplicate too. Work with that too please.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here. Firstly, the first CSS code you provided is incomplete.

Secondly, as I looked through your code, I realized that you interchanged the positioning of the elements. You should use absolute position on the parent element and relative on the contents of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

For this design, you must have a box that contains three columns and have two contents in the left column and the contents in the other columns are in the center.

Comment: 3 columns got it and Jason0011 thanks for the help I appreciate it I should be able to make the rest of the cards now

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve this in minimum div this is example for your single card you can make further changes in it.**

```css
.box1_1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 262px;
  height: 276px;
  background: gray;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 44px;
  box-shadow: -10.746728897094727px 9.851167678833008px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09000000357627869);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.box1_3 {
    padding-top: 20%;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10;
}
.box1_2{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
  height: 35%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-shadow: -10.746728897094727px 9.851167678833008px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09000000357627869); /* Add the same box-shadow as the parent container */
}
```

```html
<div class="box1_1">
    <div class="box1_3">
        <p>CAREY</p>
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box1_2">
    <p>On 56 Points</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming for the rest of the cards I would need to put them in a container. And the the 2 cards on the left in a seperate container am I correct?

Comment: you can adjust position accordingly.  just create a parent  div in each card to manage  your position.